# The Paypal tag doesn't seem to be sorting by votes correctly

Tags: bug, tags, sorting

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal?sort=votes&pageSize=15

On my browser that shows many questions with very low score. The next page shows questions with higher scores.

It looks like each individual page is sorted by votes, descending, but the paging has gone a bit funny.
It doesn't appear to do this with other tags.

This happens with any of the pages sizes available.

Comment: Correction, the problem is still there with different page sizes, just a different mix.

Comment: Not the same, but related phantom bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220187/newest-question-list-of-regex-showing-old-questions-on-first-few-pages In my case, the questions didn't sort by time correctly.

Comment: Sorting is working properly for me.